# Facebook Graph API - Less Information Retrieved

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have started using facebook API and I have noticed something strange.

I want to make a list with all the people in the guest list of the event: https://www.facebook.com/events/1565045953740088/. As you can see the event has 25k that went to the event, 925 on the maybe status and 19k in the invited status, so a total of around 45k. Using the Graph API Explorer, I have used the following code to retrieve the names of all the people:

```
GET/v2.4/1565045953740088/attending?limit=5000
GET/v2.4/1565045953740088/declined?limit=5000
GET/v2.4/1565045953740088/maybe?limit=5000
GET/v2.4/1565045953740088/noreply?limit=5000
```

After scrolling through the pages, and copy-pasting all the results in an excel, the total number of people I am getting is somewhere around 39,839. I am missing around 5k of people. Am I missing something in the code I am using?

P.S. The reason for setting the `limit` to 5000 and not to e.g. 25000 is because the page would freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people can have disabled the Graph API integration for their Facebook account. That means that you will never be able to retrieve information from them; for example their attendance for Events. They are simply ignored from the responses. This could explain for the few thousand people you are missing.

From your side, there is no workaround for this.